# Windows log generator

Tags: .net, event-viewer

Is there a way to generate specific Windows events?

I'm currently developing a solution to get this events through WMI process, but I need all the logs Windows can generate.

I know there is a way to make .net solution to write the events to the event viewer, but I don't want that.

Is there a way to code or make a solution to make Windows to generate the events? Or what any other approach do you recommend me?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "windows events"?

Comment: for example: CEF:0|Microsoft|Microsoft Windows||||audit success|cid=4 input=ela evt_asset_type=System RecordNumber=6749 process=Security category=System Event eventid=515 start=2010/07/20 22:42:16 username=NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM logname=Security dhost=SNAKE lid=0 msg=A trusted logon process has registered with the Local Security Authority.  This logon process will be trusted to submit logon requests.          Logon Process Name: Winlogon\MSGina

Comment: That is eventid 515, I want to Windows to generate all the possible eventid's

Comment: Why? Most events only make sense if from the correct source (e.g. a DHCP event from anything other than the networking drivers would be only a source of confusion).

Answer (score 1):

No. The events are not generated by Windows itself -- Windows is just reporting what the underlying application said it wanted to put into the event log. You would have to lookup documentation on the various events every given Windows component could generate, because that is the domain of each specific component, not of the event logging system itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple listener in **Visual Studio** 2015 that directs your output to a Windows EventLog.

1. Create a new Project in Visual Studio.
2. Open **App.config** and add Listener's configuration

> ```
> <system.diagnostics>
>   <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
>     <listeners>
>       <add name="myListener"
>         type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener"
>         initializeData="TraceListenerLog" />
>     </listeners>
>   </trace>
> </system.diagnostics>
> ```

[image]

3. Go to your main **Program.cs** file and the following code

> ```
> using System.Diagnostics;
>
> namespace ConsoleApplication1
> {
>     class Program
>     {
>         static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             Trace.WriteLine("Test output");
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

[image]

4. Run your application.
   [image]
5. Check your Windows Event log.
   [image]
6. If you need EXE file you can find in your Documents\visual studio 2015\your project
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

No you can't generate Windows events.

But if you want to find out what events you might encounter - have a look at the following for a complete list of Windows Events:

[Security Event Descriptions (Microsoft Site)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174074/en-us)

[Windows Security Log Events (Ultimate Windows Security)](http://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/default.aspx)

Comment: Links without explanation generally speaking do not make good answers.